# RIP Richard Hatch

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

I am sad to report that Richard Hatch, most famous for playing [Captain Apollo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Apollo) in the original Battlestar Galactica, [Tom Zarek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Zarek) in the rebooted series (as well as co-authoring a highly successful [series of Battlestar Galactica books](https://www.librarything.com/series/Battlestar+Galactica%3A+Hatch+Relaunch)) has died at the age of 71.